# collection view's delegate conforms to another protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using [CollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/ecerney/CollectionViewWaterfallLayout). In the "How to use" section, it says

> Your collection view's delegate must conforms to
>   CollectionViewWaterfallLayoutDelegate protocol and implement the
>   required method, all you need to do is return the original size of the
>   item:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

What should I do here? How to make collection view's delegate conform to CollectionViewWaterfallLayoutDelegate protocol ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while declaring your class did you wrote the code to conform to the UICollectionViewDelegae. sample code below :

```
class myViewController : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {

...

}
```

Comment: I tried  `class SearchPhotosViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, CollectionViewWaterfallLayoutDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {}`but it didn't work. The error "Type SearchPhotosViewController does not conform to protocol CollectionViewWaterfall LayoutDelegate"

Comment: have you implemented all the required methods mentioned in CollectionViewWaterfallLayoutDelegate?

Answer (score 2):

In your main view controller add `CollectionViewWaterfallLayoutDelegate` so it will be like

```
class SearchPhotosViewController: UIViewController, CollectionViewWaterfallLayoutDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource { 

//inside this call the delegate method to return the size of the item

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(300, 300)//return the CGSize for the item you want
    }
}
```